# compare values in list and change if necessary

Tags: list, client-object-model, feature

So guys, I have a sharepoint list with and fields like "webID, url, rating" and a c# list with more or less the same fields. My task is to compare the lists by webID and if the row's "rating" field is different than in my c# list then I would like to update it accordingly. This would happen in a feature's event receiver.

What would be the fastest and best approach to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CAML-query to get all the items which webID doesn't match your C# list's value and then update it.

This [blog](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list) should get you started as it also applies for the client object model.

These two should also be helpfull:

1. [Client Object Model Basic Example – CAMLQuery](http://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/2010/12/20/client-object-model-basic-example-camlquery/)
2. [CAML and the Client Object Model](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/caml-and-the-client-object-model/)